# How to render a PDF in React

Tags: reactjs, pdf, react-pdf

I'm using react-pdf and according to their site it should display my PDF using this code

```
import React from "react";
import { Document, Page } from "react-pdf";

import PDF from "./123.pdf";

export default function Rosters() {
  return (
    <div className> <h1 className='text-light'>HELLO</h1>
      <Document file={PDF}>
        <Page pageNumber={1} />
      </Document>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The problem is my PDF is not being displayed and all I'm getting is "Failed to load PDF file" error
[image] this happens in the site where the PDF should be being rendered.

I tried with different PDF files but none of them seem to work.

react-pdf documentation: https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-pdf

Comment: Check the location of "123.pdf"

Answer (score 0):

If your pdfs are located anywhere in `src` then it won't work.
Make sure you put them in the `public` folder.